# Where and how to get copyright on document

Tags: copyright

I am an indian. I need copyright in my documents. So where and how to get copyright ?

> the document is also in digital formet

Answer (score 4):

The copyright office for the government of [India](http://copyright.gov.in/) contains the information that you want. You should consult a local copyright attorney.

[copyright office contact information](http://copyright.gov.in/frmContactUs.aspx)

> Dr. V.P.Srivastav
>   Dy. Registrar of Copyrights
>   Copyright Division.
>   Department of Higher Education
>   Ministry of Human Resource Development
>   4th Floor, Jeevan Deep Building
>   Parliament Street
>   New Delhi : 110001
>
> Email Address:  mailto:copyright@nic.in
>   Office Telephone No.: 91-11-23362436

[FAQ](http://copyright.gov.in/frmFAQ.aspx)

> **Questions** :
>   Ques: What is copyright?
>   Ques: What is the scope of protection in the Copyright Act, 1957?
>   Ques: Does copyright apply
>   to titles and names?
>   Ques: Is it necessary to register a work to claim copyright?
>
> Ans: No. Acquisition of copyright is automatic and it does not require
>   any formality. Copyright comes into existence as soon as a work is
>   created and no formality is required to be completed for acquiring
>   copyright. However, certificate of registration of copyright and the
>   entries made therein serve as prima facie evidence in a court of law
>   with reference to dispute relating to ownership of copyright.
>
> Ques: Where I can file application for registration of copyright for a work?
>
> Ans: The Copyright Office has been set up to provide registration
>   facilities to all types of works and is headed by a Registrar of
>   Copyrights and is located at 4th Floor Jeevan Deep Building , New
>   Delhi- 110 001. The applications for registration of works can be
>   filled at the counter provided at the Copyright Office from 2.30 P.M.
>   to 4.30. P.M. from Monday to Friday. The applications are also
>   accepted by post. On-line registration through “E-filing facility “
>   has been provided from 14th February 2014, which facilitates the
>   applicants to file applications at the time and place chosen by them.
>
> Ques: What is the procedure for registration of a work under the Copyright 
>   Act, 1957?
>
> Ans: The procedure for registration is as follows:
>   a) Application for registration is to be made on Form IV ( Including
>   Statement of Particulars and Statement of Further Particulars) as
>   prescribed in the first schedule to the Rules ;
>
> b) Separate applications should be made for registration of each work;
>
> c) Each application should be accompanied by the requisite fee
>   prescribed in the second schedule to the Rules ; and
>
> d) The applications should be signed by the applicant or the advocate
>   in whose favor a Vakalatnama or Power of Attorney has been executed.
>   The Power of Attorney signed by the party and accepted by the advocate
>   should also be enclosed.
>
> e) The fee is either in the form of Demand Draft,Indian Postal Order
>   favoring "Registrar Of Copyright Payable At New Delhi" or through E
>   payment
>
> Each and every column of the Statement of Particulars and Statement of
>   Further Particulars should be replied specifically.
>
> Ques: What is
>   the fee for registration of a work under the Copyright Act, 1957?
>   Ques: Can I myself file an application for registration of copyright
>   of a work directly?
>
> Ans: Yes. Any individual who is an author or rights owner or assignee
>   or legal heir can file application for copyright of a work either at
>   the copyright office or by post or by e-filing facility from the
>   copyright Office web-site "www.copyright.gov.in"
>
> Ques: What are the guidelines regarding registration of a work under the Copyright Act?
>
> Ans: Chapter XIII of the Copyright Rules, 2013, as amended, sets out
>   the procedure for the registration of a work. Copies of the Act and
>   Rules can be obtained from the Manager of Publications, Publication
>   Branch, Civil Lines, Delhi or his authorized dealers on payment or
>   download from the Copyright Office web-site "www.copyright.gov.in"
>
> Ques: Whether unpublished works are registered?
>
> Ans: Yes. Both published and unpublished works can be registered.
>   Copyright in works published before 21st January, 1958, i.e., before
>   the Copyright Act, 1957 came in force, can also be registered,
>   provided the works still enjoy copyright. Three copies of published
>   work may be sent along with the application. If the work to be
>   registered is unpublished, a copy of the manuscript has to be sent
>   along with the application for affixing the stamp of the Copyright
>   Office in proof of the work having been registered. In case two copies
>   of the manuscript are sent, one copy of the same duly stamped will be
>   returned, while the other will be retained, as far as possible, in the
>   Copyright Office for record and will be kept confidential. It would
>   also be open to the applicant to send only extracts from the
>   unpublished work instead of the whole manuscript and ask for the
>   return of the extracts after being stamped with the seal of the
>   Copyright Office.
>
> When a work has been registered as unpublished and subsequently it is
>   published, the applicant may apply for changes in particulars entered
>   in the Register of Copyright in Form V with prescribed fee.
>   The process of registration and fee for registration of copyright is same.
>
> Ques: Whether computer Software or Computer Programme can be registered?
>
> Ans: Yes. Computer Software or programme can be registered as a
>   ‘literary work’. As per Section 2 (o) of the Copyright Act, 1957
>   “literary work” includes computer programmes, tables and compilations,
>   including computer databases. ‘Source Code’ has also to be supplied
>   along with the application for registration of copyright for software
>   products.
>
> Ques: How can I get copyright registration for my Web-site?
>
> A web-site contains several works such as literary works, artistic
>   works (photographs etc.), sound recordings, video clips, cinematograph
>   films and broadcastings and computer software too. Therefore, a
>   separate application has to be filed for registration of all these
>   works.
>
> Ques: How long I have to wait to get
>   my work to get registered by the Copyright office?
>
> Ans: After you file your application and receive diary number you
>   have to wait for a mandatory period of 30 days so that no objection is
>   filed in the Copyright office against your claim that particular work
>   is created by you. If such objection is filed it may take another one
>   month time to decide as to whether the work could be registered by the
>   Registrar of Copyrights after giving an opportunity of hearing the
>   matter from both the parties.
>
> If no objection is filed the application goes for scrutiny from the
>   examiners. If any discrepancy is found the applicant is given 30 days
>   time to remove the same. Therefore, it may take 2 to 3 months time for
>   registration of any work in the normal course. The cooperation of the
>   applicant in providing necessary information is the key for speedy
>   disposal the matter.
>
> Ques: Is an
>   opportunity for hearing given in all the cases pertain to rejection of
>   registration?

Comment: This is actually a really, _really_ bad answer - what happens if the copyright office changes the url and your link no longer works? Please [edit] your answer to quote some of the pertinent information, as it should really be in the text of the answer.

Comment: @jimsug - Given that [the question itself was really, *really* bad](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/416/dealing-with-questions-that-show-no-effort) a "[LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com)" answer like this *might* be the best answer.  It did prompt me to raise the question in meta....

Comment: While I was tempted to say "google is your friend" and just give the first couple of google pointers, I did feel sorry for him. Also since someone who is more experienced using this site suggested copying in the answers from the FAQ I did so. Usually on sites like stackoverflow.com, it would have been closed with "show your initial work".

Comment: If it should've been closed, then we should have closed it. If it's not worth giving an answer that has some content, maybe it's not worth answering at all.

Comment: @jimsug and sabbahillel: Both good arguments.  Please weigh in on http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/416/dealing-with-questions-that-show-no-effort!